# I want a table in Reportviewer with added information after every line

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I am using VB.NET and Report-viewer. I am able to get a data from dataset to the table in ReportViewer. But i want that after every line i can print extra information related to that row. How can i go about it?

E.g. My DataTable Fields are ::  [S.No,  Name, Amount, Notes]. I want to print something like this,

1. Customer1 100.00 
   Note for line1-----
2. Customer2 200.00
   Note for line2----

and so on. Any suggestions?

Comment: When do you want input the notes? From report, code...?

Comment: @oscarvady From Code

Comment: Is the extra information already in the data?  Or is it coming from some other source?

Comment: @AnnL. already in data.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a matrix of some kind in your report, and that your data table fields are in the Detail section of the matrix.

I think all you'll have to do is add another detail row to your matrix.

You can do this by right-clicking on the "row header" of the detail row.  Click your matrix until the grey frame around the top and left side appears, and then right-click on the left-side box with the triple horizontal lines.  That's your detail row header.

Click on the `Insert Row` menu option, and choose `Inside Group - Below` as the detail menu option.  You will now have a second detail row.

If you have multiple fields in the matrix already, your new row will probably have multiple text boxes in it.  If you want to merge them so that you have one big text box (suitable for long strings of extra information) you can select all the textboxes in that row, right click, and take the option `Merge Cells`.

You can now drag and drop your extra data into this textbox, or change the expression of that text box to refer to your Notes field, or whatever else makes sense.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Let me try this and get back. It seems it will work. Thanks in advance.